# VBA - Two loops to perform actions

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have two sheets with dynamic tables on two separate sheets generated through export from a database.

I want to loop over those two tables and perform some actions but since I am a beginner I am struggling a bit. The actions to perform are the following:

Table 1: loop over column 1 of table 1 and keep the value of the cell in a variable as string

Inside this loop go to table 2: loop over column 1 of table 2 and

IF (cell value of column 1 of table 2 = cell value of column 1 of table 1)

(go to column 4 of table 2 and copy paste the value in a new table in a new sheet only if the value is not yet paste in this new table)

exit loop 2

exit loop 1

At the end I should have x new sheets depending on the number of row in table 1 containing.

I edited my post with the following code that I have:

```
Dim rowValue As String
Dim rowValue2 As String
Dim row2 As Integer
Dim row As Integer

LastRowCopy = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastRowPaste = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Sheets("TestPerimeter")
Range("A1").Select
For row = 2 To LastRow

    Sheets("TestData")
    For row2 = 1 To LastRow2
        If Cells(row2, 1) = Cells(row, 1) Then
        With ThisWorkbook
            .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = Cells(row2,4).Value
        End With    
        End If
    Next row2

Next row
```

But still the code is not well written, I know.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid the question **isn't** clear enough. It seems as if you spent so much time giving us the background of what you you want to achieve that you forgot to mention the actual problem you were having.

Comment: I am actually a beginner in VBA and I don't have enough knowledge in the language to achieve this.

The current code that I have is the following:

Comment: Well Stack Overflow won't be the right site for you then.  Stack Overflow isn't designed as a "code for me" site (it's not setup to pass the payments from you to whoever does the work for you) nor even as a tutorial site.

Comment: Ahh - just saw that "The current code that I have" bit at the end of the comment.  (I don't think it was there when I started writing my last comment.)  If you have code that isn't working, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47091667/edit) the question to show that code (don't try to put it into comments) and explain which bit of the code is **currently** stopping you from progressing.  That **is** on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this piece of code will help you... I added comments to guide you a little. Adapt it with your table names, try it and try to understand whats happening. There were some logical errors in your code...

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim wOne As Worksheet
    Dim wTwo As Worksheet
    Dim wTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowTOne As Long
    Dim lastRowTTwo As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim matchCheck As String
    Dim y As Long

    'Save a reference to the two Table Objects
    Set wOne = Worksheets("Table1") 'Your Tablename ("TestPerimeter"?) instead of "Table1"
    Set wTwo = Worksheets("Table2") 'Your Tablename ("TestData"?) instead of "Table2"


    'Getting the last rows for each table
    lastRowTOne = wOne.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastRowTTwo = wTwo.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Pointer for the row in the new target sheet
    y = 1

    For i = 2 To lastRowTOne
        matchCheck = wOne.Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = 1 To lastRowTTwo
            If wTwo.Cells(j, 1).Value = matchCheck Then
                'If there is a first match, create a new sheet
                If y = 1 Then
                    Set wTarget = Worksheets.Add
                End If
                'add the matching string
                wTarget.Cells(y, 1).Value = matchCheck
                'increase the pointers value
                y = y + 1
                'here you found a match... so exit this loop
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice it helps a lot.
Just a question regarding:

    Set wOne = Worksheets("Table1") 'Your Tablename ("TestPerimeter"?) instead of "Table1"
    Set wTwo = Worksheets("Table2") 'Your Tablename ("TestData"?) instead of "Table2"

TestPerimeter and testData are the name of the worksheet. So I will put the tablename instead: setTestPerimeter and setTestData. Do I need to give precision on the worksheet? Or wOne = Worksheets("setTestPerimeter") is enough?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you mean by: "Do I need to give precision on the worksheet?"

Comment: There are different ways to access a table object. 1. Directly by its name "(Name)" - Property in the VBA Editor. 2. By its Worksheet name (as I've done it) 3. By its number, like Worksheets(2) for example 4..... and so on

Comment: I mean: does worksheets("setTestPerimeter") automatically go to the correct worksheets where the tablename setTestPerimeter is?
Question 2: in my two loops I start with counter i and j = 2 because my table has a header. Is it correct?

Comment: 1. yes 2. yes syntax is table.cells(rownumber, columnnumber) rownumber starts on 2 so everythings fine... You may not hard-code it. you can add a startColumnT2 constant at the beginning and use this instead of the number 2. It would enable you to change this offset easily if the code is getting bigger...

Answer (score 0):

I made some modification to your script and I have this now:

```
Sub test()
Dim wOne As Worksheet
Dim wTwo As Worksheet
Dim wTarget As Worksheet
Dim lastRowTOne As Long
Dim lastRowTTwo As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim matchCheck As String
Dim y As Long

'Save a reference to the two Table Objects
Set wOne = Worksheets("t_test_perimeter") '<- compilation error here when I do a mouse over on the error I have: Worksheets("t_test_perimeter") = <Subscript out of range>
Set wTwo = Worksheets("t_test_data")


'Getting the last rows for each table
lastRowTOne = wOne.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastRowTTwo = wTwo.UsedRange.Rows.Count


For i = 2 To lastRowTOne
    'Pointer for the row in the new target sheet
    y = 1
    matchCheck = Right(wOne.Cells(i, 1).Value, Len(wOne.Cells(i, 1).Value) - 4)
    For j = 2 To lastRowTTwo
        If wTwo.Cells(j, 1).Value = matchCheck Then
            'If there is a first match, create a new sheet
            If y = 1 Then
                Set wTarget = Worksheets.Add
            End If
            'add the matching string
            wTarget.Cells(y, 1).Value = wTwo.Cells(j, 9)
            'increase the pointers value
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Can someone give me info on the error? In my excel file when I click on a cell of the table then do CTRL+A: I get the tablename in the upper-left field next to the formula bar. Is it not correct to use this tablename in the VBA code?

Thanks a lot. I found a solution by not selecting the table but just the worksheet and it works well now.